# sorting files with Python natsort and save it to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a bloody beginner with python and need to sort a list (reverse) with files. I googled alot and it seems natsort gives the solution for my problem.

I found the ducumentation https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html but I do not manage to apply it to my case. I have a list in search_results.txt and want it to be sorted with natsort

```
Input:
C:/Test/XY2019_00.zip 
C:/Test/XY2019_01-04.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-03.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-02.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-01.zip

Output with normal sort (reverse = True):
C:/Test/XY2019_01.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-04.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-03.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-02.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-01.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_00.zip


desired result:
C:/Test/XY2019_01-04.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-03.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-02.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01-01.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_01.zip
C:/Test/XY2019_00.zip
```

---

```
import pathlib
from natsort import natsort_key

paths = list()
#read results from file
filename = 'search_results.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        paths.append(line.strip())

sorted(paths, key=lambda x: tuple(natsort_key(s) for s in pathlib.Path(x).parts))
```

```
I do not get an error, but I do not manage to get the result again into my search_result.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now:

```
def sorting ():
    from natsort import os_sorted

    paths = list()
    # read results from file
    filename = 'search_results.txt'
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            paths.append(line.strip())


    results = os_sorted(paths, reverse=True)

    filename = 'search_results.txt'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for result in results:
            f.write(result + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the sorting algorithm but the fact that `.z` comes after `-0`. The extensions are part of the string and this may mess up your sorting order.

To prevent that from happening, you have to remove the `.zip` extensions from the filename prior to sorting. You can store the filename without extension in the same list as the correct filename and sort it zipped to just extract the real filenames in the end:

```
flist = []
for f in filenames:
    flist.append((f[:-4],f))

filesorted = list(zip(*sorted(flist,reverse=True)))[1]
```

The list `filesorted` then contains the correct order.
If your folder contains files with extensions longer than 4 chars (e.g. .xlsx), you may have to use a more sophisticated trunctuation than `f[:-4]`, but it should work fine.

Comment: I thought natsort just solves the issue that `.z` comes befor `.-` an is applicable for all extensions. Anway. I should only have 3 characters. Howerver unfortunatelly it does not work. It writes only one (seemingly random) letter in the list.

Comment: list: '['x', 'u', 't', 't', 't', 's', 's', 's', 'r', 'r', 'l', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'a', '_', '.']'

Comment: I assumed that you have the filenames as strings in a list called `filenames`. Sorry for not mentioning it. It seems, you just gave one string into the loop.
The code works for any list of strings, where the last four characters of the string (e.g. `.zip`) should not be regarded while sorting. So, yes: It works for all extensions.